# How to remove trailing additional slash yii

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-url-manager

When using the

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/page/');
```

it is additing additional trailing slash to the url LIKE http://www.sitename//  AND http://www.sitename//page

That I need to exclude two slashes, Application url manager is as follow,

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlSuffix' => '/',
        'rules' => array(
            'site/news_letter_unsubsubscribe/<id:\w+>' => 'site/news_letter_unsubsubscribe',
            'page/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'page/index/',
            'site/blog_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/blog_detail',
            'location/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'location/index',
            'auth/partner_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'auth/partner_detail',
            //'tour/tour_detail/<id:\w+>/<date:\w+>'=>'tour/tour_detail',
            'activity/activity_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'activity/activity_detail',
            'activity/compare_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'activity/compare_detail',
            'tour/tour_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'tour/tour_detail',
            'tour/compare_detail/<id:[\w\-]+>' => 'tour/compare_detail',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'auth/reset_password/<id:\w+>' => 'auth/reset_password',
            'site/linkedin_login/<id:\w+>' => 'site/linkedin_login',

        ),
    )
```

.htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Remove urSuffix '/' from the urlManager and give it a try.

Comment: No that't was not the isse

Answer (score 2):

In Yii2 your code is wrong. You are reading [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-url-handling.html)! Example:

```
echo \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('page');
```

Comment: Thx for the reply,I corrected this. but still shows two slashes after the domain name

Comment: I could sort this issue removing the suffix slash from request base url Thx

Answer (score 0):

I could sort this issue removing the suffix slash  from request base url

Thanks